# How to parse the xml file have same tag name using nsxmlparser?

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsxmlparser

How do I parse this type of XML using NSXMLParser

```
<category> <categoryName> userName</categoryName> <categoryName>password</categoryName><category>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare array and a string in h file like:

```
 NSMutableArray *aryCategory;
 NSString *strCategroyName;
```

in .m file for starting Parser use:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:yourData]; // your data will be instance of NSData or NSMutableData
parser.delegate = self;
[parser parse];
```

this will be done once you get your xml data. For handling result you can use `NSXMLParserDelegate` as follows:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"category"]) {
          aryCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
          strCategroyName = @"";
     }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
     strCategroyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", strCategroyName, string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"categoryName"]) {
          [aryCategory addObject:strCategroyName];
          strCategroyName = @"";
     }
```

}

Now you will have your array fill with all of your category name.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Write the `<category>` in `didStart` and `didEnd` elements which are the parser's delegates.

Comment: but the categoryname have two values how can parse that